# Should we allow questions about the coronavirus?

Tags: discussion

As the flood of information, from around the world, comes in concerning the pandemic; should we create a [coronavirus-bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coronavirus-bioinformatics) tag and try to apply the principals of bioinformatics to it? This may help lighten the load on Biology.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say I've generally been against these questions since inevitably they're off-topic. I think the only regular on the site that has a relevant background to answer these is Michael G.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever you think, the problem isn't nearly as bad as "Biology SE". One of the questions was **"Can Coronavirus hitch a ride on a perfume particle"** !!! Oh dear, good job they are not posting here, it certainly gives a whole new twist to the miasma theory :-) . [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miasma_theory) in case you are wondering.

In contrast, I found alot of the questions on Bioinfo SE ahead of the curve and helpful.

At present two areas of bioinformatics that are relevant to COVID-19: phylogenetics and epidemiological modelling. Protein modelling is currently frustrated due to the lack of structural information for accurate modelling,

Epidemiological modelling isn't considered bioinformatics. Phylogenetics is a not a huge disapline. When accurate protein structures start kicking in, or big NGS dumps, then I think we'd have questions that would appeal to the numerous structural modellers and bioinformaticians present on the site.

My advice is just be patient and definitely try and avoid becoming "a patient" when its about COVID-19.

Comment: citation: [Can a virus hitch a ride on an odour particle?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92454/can-a-virus-hitch-a-ride-on-an-odour-particle)

Comment: I am in physics forum. There have been questions like "can coronavirus use quantum tunneling" and "can we kill coronavirus with ultrasound". They are generally dismissed as off-topic.

Comment: It would give a whole new meaning to R0